# How to display category name in products details page for bigcommerce

Tags: e-commerce

I need to display category name on products details page in my bigcommerce store.
I tried to get using `%%GLOBAL_CatId%%` variable but it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the category breadcrumbs are in the theme, you could grab it from there with jQuery.

I think the current category is the next to the last in the list. You can try this:

```
$('.Breadcrumb').find('li:nth-last-child(2)');
```

You can put that into a div on your ProductDetails page.